# Tokenizing content of a field differently depending on language - Apache Solr

Tags: solr

I've got a field in Apache Solr called "content", and the field is currently being indexed/tokenized as an English language field, which isn't always true, sometimes it has Japanese.

Is there anyway to process this field differently depending on language? Perhaps if there's an `fq="language:japanese` (pseudocode) or something like that?

What's the best way to allow processing for multiple languages on a single field.

We've currently got a second field with the same content that is set to Japanese language, but we'd really like the processing to go on this one field.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to the Solr [LanguageDetection](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageDetection) feature. It supports automatic renaming / mapping of fields according to detected language and other advanced parameters.

In your case, an idea would be to map `content` to `content_en` and `content_ja` according to the language detected into `content`. Here an example of the UpdateRequestProcessor definition in solrconfig.xml :

```
 <processor class="org.apache.solr.update.processor.TikaLanguageIdentifierUpdateProcessorFactory">
   <bool name="langid">true</bool>
   <str name="langid.fl">content</str>  <!-- list of fields to be processed -->
   <str name="langid.langField">language</str>  <!-- where goes returned langcode -->
   <str name="langid.whitelist">en,ja</str>  <!-- what language to detect -->
   <bool name="langid.map">true</bool>  <!-- mapping langcode (add _suffix) -->
   <str name="langid.map.lcmap">en_GB:en en_US:en</str>  <!-- custom mapping -->
 </processor>
```

You will have to update schema.xml so that both `content_en` and `content_ja` are defined, and ensure that they are binded to the corresponding fieldtype for indexation.

Comment: How do you detect a specific language in content? Like, what is doing that?

Comment: It is an [UpdateRequestProcessor](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRequestProcessor) using Tika or LangDetect implementations (Tika is used in the example). Edit solrconfig.xml to define an [UpdateRequestProcessorChain](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_7_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/UpdateRequestProcessorChain.html) where you can put processors definition. Then edit your update requestHandler to declare the use of your procesor chains.